# Cинхронизация андроид приложения с сервером когда подключен интернет

Tags: php, java, mysql, laravel, sqlite

Как синхронизировать база данных андроид приложения с база данных сервера когда в бек-енде можно использовать Laravel и Mysql

Comment: я извиняюсь, а причем тут PHP?

Comment: что вы используйте для того (когда андроид приложение работает на база данных sqlite в офлайн режиме и когда подключим интернет чтоб все данные передавалась на база данных сервера)

Comment: ну что угодно :) Можно и jdbc.